# PHP Clause Priority

Tags: php

i have the following logic which works fine

`['Value']` is tinyint(1)
`['Text1']` varchar(200)
`['Text2']` varchar(200)

```
if ($item['Table']['Value'] == 0) then Option 1

if ($item['Table']['Value'] && $e['Table']['Text1']) then Option 2

if ($item['Table']['Value'] && $e['Table']['Text1'] == false) then Option 3
```

I want to add one more Option with highest Priority If any Text in [‘Text2’] regardless if [‘Value’] = 1 or 0

I tried add than one on the top , but as anyone smarter than me would suggest it did not work att all.

```
if ($item['Table']['Text2'] == true) then Option 4
```

Please tell how the proper structure of such logic should look like.
Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't option 4 mean that option 2 can never be set?

Answer (score 0):

If i get your question right, you should use `else if` for such cases like:

```
if ($item['Table']['Text2'] == true) then Option 4

else if ($item['Table']['Value'] == 0) then Option 1

else if ($item['Table']['Value'] && $e['Table']['Text1']) then Option 2

else if ($item['Table']['Value'] && $e['Table']['Text1'] == false) then Option 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with `empty` condition

```
if (!empty($item['Table']['Text2'])) then Option 4
if ($item['Table']['Value'] == 0) then Option 1

if ($item['Table']['Value'] && $e['Table']['Text1']) then Option 2

if ($item['Table']['Value'] && $e['Table']['Text1'] == false) then Option 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `if ... else...` structure allows you to create a hierarchy for the combinations.  At the moment, some test are done a few times, when they could be factored out.  This also (IMHO) makes the conditions clearer and easier to maintain...

```
if ( !empty($e['Table']['Text1']) ) {
    // Option 4
}
else {
    if ($item['Table']['Value'] == 0)   {
        // Option 1
    }
    else    {
        if (!empty($e['Table']['Text1']))  {
            //Option 2
        }
        else    {
            // Option 3
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in my comment to the question itself - not sure if Option 2 is achievable as this would now be Option 4.

Comment: Hi, thank you all for your help. It works fine now. Thank you! that place rulzzz